# Obter dados do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<?php
$verifica = mysqli_query("SELECT * from dados WHERE login='$login'");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($verifica);

$array[senha];

?>
```

Supostamente, eu quero obter os dados do login, onde login é igual a variavel $login, e depois exibir a senha do mesmo, contudo aparece-me os seguintes erros:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\adm\logar.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\adm\logar.php on line 10

O que está de errado?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você não está esquecendo de passar o parâmetro de conexão para o mysqli? E outra, você está misturando as bibliotecas. Se começou com mysqli, não pode mudar abruptamente para mysql(que está até depreciada).

Comment: Como assim passar o parametro? é que eu sou do tempo do mysql_query.

Comment: Veja: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Não consegui perceber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) em modo procedural, espera uma variável com parâmetros para criar uma conexão com o banco e outra com a query propriamente dita, você só está passando a query.

Tente assim:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

$verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from dados WHERE login='$login'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica);

$array['senha'];
```

Porém, a consulta ficaria muito vulnerável desta forma, você poderia parametrizar essa query, desta forma:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");
//prepara a query pra receber o parametro ?
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT senha from dados WHERE login= ?");
//passa o parametro e o tipo("s" quer dizer string)
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $login);
//executa a query
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//vincula o retorno a variavel $verifica
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $verifica);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
printf($verifica);// exibe a senha
/* fecha o statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Isso diminui um pouco a vulnerabilidade, mas não significa que o código está seguro apenas com isso.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário passar os parâmetros de conexão quando se usa as funções mysqli_query, e como o camarada disse, tente não usar misturar as duas bibliotecas.

Mais sobre o mysqli: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Boa Noite, Eu não consegui perceber muito essa biblioteca mysqli, como posso aplicar ao meu caso?